# Show / Hide div - scroll to activated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a show/hide bit of functionality. Only one accordion can be open at a time. The problem I'm having is sometimes when a new one opens up the text will be half way down. So it won't be at the start of the accordion. I'd like it to scroll to the top of the open accordion.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/e6fpfa68/

```
<a class="showBtn">BUTTON</a>
<div class="hideme">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
</div>

<a class="showBtn">BUTTON 2</a>
<div class="hideme">
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.showBtn').click(function() {
  //$('.hideme').hide();  
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {    
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.hideme').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('.hideme').slideUp();
    $('.showBtn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).next().filter('.hideme').slideDown();
  }
});
```

I've been trying to mess around with:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scroll_to}, 2000);
```

but it's not giving the correct result (http://jsfiddle.net/e6fpfa68/2/).

What would be the best way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach in the second fiddle is quite good. Use jQuery.position() as the target of the second animation but more importantly you have to do it after the first animation finished, in it's callback:

```
$('.showBtn').click(function() {  
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {    
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.hideme').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('.hideme').slideUp();
    $('.showBtn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).next().filter('.hideme').slideDown(400, function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).position().top}, 400);
    });
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e6fpfa68/8/

Comment: When I put this in my code it made it go back to the top of the page. However I put offset where position was and it suddenly worked as it was supposed to! So thank you! Here's what I ended up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/e6fpfa68/21/

Comment: also your jsfiddle links to a different one.. it uses scrollIntoView .. is that a plugin?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the Fiddles. I lost one with the posted code. Your solution is good but two animations taking place sequentially is not the best UX. A little rethought, here is a version with one animation. This animates the vertical offset of the body scroll position - _in parallel_ with the menu content opening animation - to be at the top of the selected menu's content either if a new menu is chosen from below or above the currently open one. http://jsfiddle.net/mm10me3w/2/

Comment: Thank you again! I'm not entirely sure how this one is working.. but the position still didn't work but it did once I changed it to offset. What is the IF statement doing? Why is it looking to see if the diff is less than 0?

Comment: Well, it checks if the body position needs to be scrolled up or down because you may click a new element below or above the open one. Anyway, glad I could be of help.